# Push to another view with UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to edit the add button to push to another view.
But I am receiving an error

```
-(void)locationAdd:(id)sender{
 if([self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
  UINavigationController *parent = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;
  if ([[parent viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] == self) { 
   LocationsAddViewController *alocationAddViewController = [[[LocationsAddViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationAddView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
   //self.locationAddViewController = alocationAddViewController;
   alocationAddViewController.title = @"Toevoegen";
   [self.parentViewController pushViewController:alocationAddViewController animated:YES];
  }
  else if([[parent viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2] == self){
   LocationsAddViewController *alocationAddViewController = [[[LocationsAddViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationAddView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
   alocationAddViewController.title = @"Toevoegen";
   [self.parentViewController pushViewController:alocationAddViewController animated:YES];
  }
 }
}
```

Because the view can be reached from 2 other views and it has to look different, I have used

```
if([self.parentViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
        UINavigationController *parent = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;
        if ([[parent viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] == self) {
```

to check where it comes from.

The problem is at:
[self.parentViewController pushViewController:alocationAddViewController animated:YES];
I am receiving the error:

+[LocationsTableViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x23510
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[LocationsTableViewController pushViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x23510'

Can someone help me?
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that you're trying to call `pushViewController:animated:` on your `LocationsTableViewController` class object.  This shouldn't be possible given the code you posted.  Are you sure you pasted in the exact code that threw the exception?  (It's suspicious that your `if` and `else if` blocks do the exact same thing.)